# connecting to mlab fails

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mlab

Trying to connect to mlab using  [this article](http://tamsler.blogspot.ru/2012/06/mongodb-connection-from-nodejs-to.html)

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var Server = mongo.Server;
var Db = mongo.Db;
var server = new Server('ds1234.mongolab.com', 12345, {auto_reconnect : true});
var db = new Db('db-name', server);
db.open(function(err, client) {
    client.authenticate('username', 'password', function(err, success) {
    // Do Something ...
    });
});
```

but there is error:

> "connect ETIMEDOUT 40.78.24.54:12345"

and client is undefined, so it can't read property "authenticate" of client
I need connect to mlab and create some collections, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You have copied the string "ds1234.mongolab.com" from the tutorial. But you can't connect to that address because it doesn't belong to you. You need to make an account on MongoLab and [Follow their instructions](http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/) for connecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //install mongodb: npm install mongodb --save
    var mongodb = require("mongodb");

     var db;
// Connect to the database before starting the application server.
//Create User on Mlab and replace the URL
     mongodb.MongoClient.connect("URL", function (err, database) { 
             if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              process.exit(1);
      }

      db = database;
      console.log("Database connection ready");
```